# Is it safe to construct Swing/AWT widgets NOT on the Event Dispatch Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, swing, awt

I've been integrating the [Substance](https://substance.dev.java.net/) look and feel into my application and ran into several problems regarding it's internal EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) checking routines. Substance absolutely refuses to construct UI classes outside of the EDT. I've done plenty of Swing/AWT and I know most of the rules regarding the EDT. I use SwingWorker, SwingUtilties.invokeLater to modify components. I always though that components could be ***CONSTRUCTED*** outside of the EDT, but must be ***realized*** and ***manipulated*** on the EDT. In other words, you can construct and setup defaults in the background but the call to pack/setVisible must be EDT as well as any subsequent calls to manipulate the component.

The reason I ask is that I have a particularly "beefy" window to construct, involving many widgets, state, and resources (lots of icons). Previously, I constructed the window on the background method of a SwingWorker and made the window visible in the done method. Never had a single problem. Upon switching to Substance, the internal EDT checking bites me.

I've been able to refactor code to get around this. I can construct on the EDT which isn't a good solution since the entire application will block. I can also refactor even more and try my best to load all of the extra resources outside of the EDT.

Wrapping it up ... Is it safe to ***construct*** Swing/AWT widgets NOT on the Event Dispatch Thread?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Sun has changed the rules in 2004 -- before, you were allowed to create the components outside the EDT and only had to move into the EDT once the component had been **realized**.

The new rule now reads:

> To avoid the possibility of deadlock,
>   you must take extreme care that Swing
>   components and models are **created**,
>   modified, and queried only from the
>   event-dispatching thread.

[this](http://netzwerg.ch/blog/2007/06/20/threads-and-swing) blog post of mine gives more details, including links to other related articles. note that all official Sun [examples](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java) have been rewritten and are very strict about this.

historically, it probably was the increasing availability of multi-core computers as desktop machines that motivated the re-formulation of the rule -- threading issues became more and more apparent on the client stack, and by being very strict on EDT guidelines, a lot of them can be prevented from the start.

Comment: sneaky sneaky ... thanks for the concrete evidence I was craving. Time to refactor!

Comment: It's more race conditions than deadlocks that cause the problem.

Comment: @tom: i agree about the race conditions -- never claimed it were the deadlocks, have i (just referred to 'threading issues')?

Comment: @tom: sorry, i missed that the quote explicitly mentions the deadlocks -- but as said before, i agree with you that it's more the race conditions...

Answer (score 9):

No.

Simple reason is that even the EDT likes to deadlock in some rare cases and in general it's easy to deadlock the UI when using Swing (*or so I've been told*). I suggest you read these three articles from Kirill's (the Substance dev) blog:

- [New article on Swing EDT violations](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=126)
- [Unwritten rule of working with Swing’s EDT](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=204)
- [Stricter checks on EDT violations in Substance](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=368)