# Swing Toolkit and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

It is said that "**Swing toolkit is not multithread-Safe?**

*What is meant by this statement?*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564388/javas-swing-threading

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429681/what-happens-when-swings-threading-policy-is-violated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Swing Libraries & Thread Safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182316/java-swing-libraries-thread-safety)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=131370

> So to simplify the implementation of
>   Swing library they chose it to be not
>   thread safe. The argument being that
>   most of the GUI related work happens
>   in the callbacks from the GUI which
>   happen on the single GUI thread
>   anyways. Granted - for long running
>   tasks the user will have to do more
>   work if he/she wants to do
>   multithreaded activity...

Specially the link given for the jfc.

And the this link: http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/devgui/vt03/out/ThreadsAndSwing.pdf

> After Swing components have been
>   displayed on the screen, they should
>   only be operated on by the
>   event-handling thread. The
>   event-handling thread (or just event
>   thread) is started automatically by
>   the Java VM when an application has a
>   graphical interface. The event thread
>   calls methods like paint() on
>   Component, actionPerformed() on
>   ActionListener, and all of the other
>   event-handling methods

---

**ADD**

Check the second link I have given, specially the section: **The Need for Worker Threads in a GUI Setting** (also there is an example for explaining it). Quoting here for reference:

> The event thread plays a critical role
>   in an application with a graphical
>   interface. Code that will be executed
>   by the event-handling thread should be
>   relatively brief and nonblocking. If
>   the event-handling thread is blocked
>   in a section of code for a while, no
>   other events can be processed!

Comment: @ Favonius why should not we have long running tasks at one event when working with swing?

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: I have updated my answer. Please check it. Also look at the links given by @andersoj in response to your question.