# When to use SwingUtilies.invokeAndWait/invokeLater

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread, concurrency

I read somewhere that for any thread that affects the visuals of the gui it should be ran in the EDT using SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait/invokeLater

For a basic gui, is it necessary to put something like `new SwingGUI().setVisible(true);` in the line of the EDT using invokeAndWait? Just to display?

Does this count?

Answer (score 9):

The short answer to your question is: yes, even calling `setVisible` should happen on the EDT. To find out whether the current thread is the EDT, you can use the [`EventQueue#isDispatchThread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#isDispatchThread()) method

Some reference links:

- [Multithreaded Swing Applications](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Threads/swing/)
- [Threads and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Edit:
after reading the links I provided, it seems some of the articles on the Oracle site are outdated as in they still document you can create Swing components on another thread. There is a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491323/is-it-safe-to-construct-swing-awt-widgets-not-on-the-event-dispatch-thread/491377#491377) on this which contains some nice answers and links to blogposts and articles about the 'new' policy (new as in a few years old)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you touch a Swing object you have to do it on the EDT. In most cases you are already there, but if not, use the `SwingUtilities` classes. The reason for this is that the Swing classes are not multi-threaded, so you are likely to cause nasty problems if you access it on other threads. And it could be that `setVisible()` is doing a lot of things under the covers to make something display (like re-laying things out). Better to be safe.

Comment: When am I not running under the EDT? So what you mean is if I make a thread for changing something I should run it with one of these methods right? But I'm not making another thread, I'm just running on the default thread right? So wouldn't doing setVisible in invokeAndWait be unnecessary?

Comment: If you are running it on the "default" (main) thread, then you are *not* on the EDT.

Comment: Have a look a the links in @Robin's answer. The main thread is not the same as the EDT thread, but often the code you are running with Swing is code to handle an event and thus on the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is called from your

```
public static void main(String[] agrs) {
```

directly (without spawning another thread or using invokeLater) is running on the main thread.

Accessing GUI objects with the main thread while they may be being accessed (simultaneously) by the EDT (which is triggered by user input) can cause threading issues. Calling invokeLater causes tasks (runnables) to run on the EDT, preventing simultaneous access by other EDT tasks ie. button presses etc.

If you can be sure the EDT is not busy (before the first window is setVisible(true)) you can access the GUI from the main thread. If you can be sure the EDT has no reference to the component you're working on (it is out of EDT's scope) ie. before it's added to any container, you can access it from main thread without the EDT accessing it simultaneously, as the EDT has no way to reach it.

Comment: No. Even is not visible yet, a window must be accessed from the EDT. See Robin's comment on Dunes's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Everything that access Swing objects should do so via the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). There is one small exception to this (which I'll mention later). The purpose of the EDT is to process any events that may occur  due to IO (mouse and keyboard events). Quite a lot of the time this can mean altering the layout of your GUI. Swing was not developed to be thread-safe, meaning that that if two thread try to modify the same component at the same time then you can end up with a corrupted GUI. Since there is already one known thread to be accessing Swing components (the EDT), no other thread should attempt to modify them or even read their state.

Now, to the exceptional case when you can manipulate Swing objects outside of the EDT. Before any components have become visible it is not possible for IO to be triggering events. Therefore, the main thread can setup a Swing GUI and then set a single JFrame to be visible. Since there is now a visible frame IO events can occur and the main thread should not try to modify any more Swing components. The should only use this option to get a GUI started, and really only with toy problems.

What I'm saying is that the following is fine and won't cause problems if you're just playing around with stuff.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create components
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    ...

    // do layout and other bits of setup


    // show gui to user
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: -1: Swing threading rules have been updated. You should access all components on the EDT, even when they are not visible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491323/is-it-safe-to-construct-swing-awt-widgets-not-on-the-event-dispatch-thread/491377#491377