# How can I make JFileChooser behave properly with disconnected network drives?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, event-dispatch-thread

When I create a JFileChooser on a system with a disconnected network drive it takes forever before the JFileChooser gets displayed.  It blocks the EDT for about 20s with a single disconnected network drive.

It seems like it would be a common problem, but I can't find a way to work around it.  Possible options I've seen are:

- use JFileDialog
- replace FileSystemView with one where getRoots() returns a fixed list of drives
- switch to a WAIT cursor before trying to open JFileChooser(s)
- create a JFileChooser at startup and keep it around forever
- try using [xfiledialog](http://code.google.com/p/xfiledialog/)

My use case is so simple that I hate to resort to a third party library.  The other options all seem pretty bad to me though.

Any other suggestions?

Maybe the guy who submitted [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4260746) bug report 13 years ago is hanging around here and has it figured out by now.

### Updated With Code and Logging Output

Here's the code I'm using for this.

```java
private void initFileChooser() {
    log.debug("Initializing fileChooser.");

    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    log.debug("FileChooser instantiation complete.");

    fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF Files", "pdf"));
    log.debug("File filter setup complete.");

    fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    log.debug("Multi-selection disabled.");

    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    log.debug("File selection mode set to files only.");
}
```

Here's the logging output when the above code runs with no disconnected network drives.

```
05:37:13.126 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG - Initializing fileChooser.
05:37:13.481 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG - FileChooser instantiation complete.
05:37:13.482 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG - File filter setup complete.
05:37:13.482 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG - Multi-selection disabled.
05:37:13.482 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG - File selection mode set to files only.
```

Here's the logging output when the above code runs with a disconnected network drive on Windows 7.  I'm creating a disconnected network drive by using [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) (1.8.4) to connect to a Linux machine and shutting down the Linux machine after the initial connection is made.

```
05:37:58.953 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG - Initializing fileChooser.
05:38:11.108 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG - FileChooser instantiation complete.
05:38:11.110 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG - File filter setup complete.
05:38:11.110 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG - Multi-selection disabled.
05:38:11.110 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG - File selection mode set to files only.
```

Comment: You might look to roll your own using [this source](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) as a starting point.

Comment: *"Maybe the guy who submitted this bug report 13 years ago is hanging around here and has it figured out by now."* If they did not mention it as a workaround in the bug report (the best place for such information), why would they mention it now?  ..Or was that sarcasm?

Comment: aaaach Now I see that some users with hot head deleted my post to your `FileBro` about hanging issue on `WinXP` for `Network Drives` and `My Network`,

Answer (score -1):

you blocked EDT, maybe with `RepaintManager` exceptions in the case that `Network Drive` isn't accesible or returns an exception, your have to

- use `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread`
- notify user `"Please wait, whatever ...."`
- if success, then to show `JFileChooser` with `Files`
- otherwise you GUI freeze until network drive returns content or exception

Comment: The delay happens when I call `new JFileChooser()`.  That call must be made on the EDT accoring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491323/is-it-safe-to-construct-swing-awt-widgets-not-on-the-event-dispatch-thread) answer.  I've updated my question with sample code and logging output.

Comment: not when Folder is once time opened, then File contents from channel is cached untill ticked expired (depend of Native OS and HW on Network side),

Comment: Previously up-voted as conceptually correct. The worker will have to do whatever is required to minimize latency when `JFileChooser` is later invoked on the EDT. For example, I have a USB spindle with a hard-coded spindown timer on which I simply `touch` a hidden file at a slightly shorter interval.