# this.addKeyListener(input); does not work, but frame.addKeyListener does (only for a short while)

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to be able to type into the display window that I have, but whenever I add in

```
this.addKeyListener(input);
```

It does absolutely nothing, but

```
frame.addKeyListener(input);
```

works, but only for a short while. After a bit of input, it throws me the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException<br>
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)<br>
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)<br>
at net.textBasedGame.Display.getInputAsString(Display.Java:52)<br>
at net.textBasedGame.Display.render(Display.java:81)
at net.textBasedGame.Display.run(Display.java:37)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My code for Display.java is here, and below is Input.java, I'm just not sure what exactly is causing

```
this.addKeyListener(input);
```

not to work.

```
package net.textBasedGame;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import.javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display extends Canvas implements Runnable {

public static final int GAMEWIDTH = 600;
public static final int GAMEHEIGHT = 600;
private boolean waitingForInput;
public boolean running;
private Input input;
private ArrayList<Character> userInput = new ArrayList<Character>();

public void run() {
init();
running = true;
waitingForInput = true;
while(running){
BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
if(bs == null){
createBufferStrategy(2);
continue;
}
Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
render(g);
bs.show();
}
}

public String getInputAsString(){
String result = "";
for(Character c: userInput){
result += c;
}
return result;

}

public void addCharToArray(Character c){
userInput.add(c);
}

public void setWaitingforInputfalse(){
waitingForInput = false;
}

public boolean isWaitingForInput(){
return waitingForInput
}

public void render(Graphics g){
Graphics 2D g1 = (Graphics2D) g;
g1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g1.fillRect(0, 0, GAMEWIDTH, GAMEHEIGHT);
g1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g1.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
g1.setColor(Color.Blue);
g1.fillRect(450, 100, 50, 50);
g1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
g1.setColor(Color.RED);
g1.drawString(getInputAsString(), 10, 300);
}

static public void main(String [] argv){
new Display().start();
}

public void start(){
Thread t = new Thread(this);
t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
t.start();
}
public void init(){
input = new Input(this);
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Based Game");
frame.setSize(GAMEWIDTH, GAMEHEIGHT);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.IgnoreRepaint(true);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.addKeyListener(input);
frame.add(this);
}
}
```

Input.java

```
package net.textBasedGame;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Input implements KeyListener {

private Display dis;
private int keyCode;

public Input(Display display){
dis = display;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyTyped(Key event e){
int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
Character keyLetter = e.getKeyChar();
if(Character.*isLetterOrDigit*(keyLetter) || keyLetter.equals('?') || Character.isSpaceChar(keyLetter)){

}
if(dis.isWaitingForInput()){
dis.addCharToArray(keyLetter);
}

else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
dis.setWaitingforInputfalse();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this exception when you modify an ArrayList while it is being iterated, and you are updating the list from one thread and iterating it from another. A quick fix is making all methods that touch the list synchronized so that no two threads can enter them at the same time; that is:

```
public synchronized String getInputAsString(){
    ....
}


public synchronized void addCharToArray(Character c){
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in general, Swing (JFrame) is not thread safe. All Swing components and related classes, unless otherwise documented, must be accessed on the event dispatching thread.

> Swing event handling code runs on a special thread known as the event
>   dispatch thread. Most code that invokes Swing methods also runs on
>   this thread. This is necessary because most Swing object methods are
>   not "thread safe": invoking them from multiple threads risks thread
>   interference or memory consistency errors.

The concept of the "Event Dispatch Thread" is explained more detail explained here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

> Where the impact lies, however, is in constructing and showing a Swing
>   application. Calls to an application's main method, or methods in
>   Applet, are not invoked on the event dispatching thread. As such, care
>   must be taken to transfer control to the event dispatching thread when
>   constructing and showing an application or applet.

And for some more info around the topic - here is a good, related answer:
[Is it safe to construct Swing/AWT widgets NOT on the Event Dispatch Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491323/is-it-safe-to-construct-swing-awt-widgets-not-on-the-event-dispatch-thread/491377#491377)