# How to debug missing frame contents in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, debugging, jframe

```
package me.daniel.practice;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Switch
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Password Login System");
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Password: ");
        JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
        pass.setEchoChar('*');
        pass.addActionListener(new AL());
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(pass, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(panel);
    }

    private static String password = "daniel";

    static class AL implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JPasswordField input = (JPasswordField) e.getSource();
            char[] passy = input.getPassword();
            String p = new String(passy);

            if (p.equals(password))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want a frame to open and within it, text that says, "Enter Password: " and on its right, a text box that you are able to type you password into. The password in this situation is "daniel."

When you enter the password correctly, another window pops up saying that it's correct. If not, a different window pops up saying that it's incorrect. However, when I run the program, only the frame shows up and not the actual content within the frame.

Comment: I just executed your code and it seems to work fine (java 7)

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, as bugs caused by thread safety issues are random and subtle, but you really should [create your Swing components on the EDT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/491377/1953590).

Comment: There's a reason why `getPassword` returns a `char` array.  For good practice, don't use `String p = new String(passy);` :P

Comment: Your title should describe your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `frame.validate();` after `frame.add(panel);`.

Although the code you have will most likely work, ideally you should wrap any Java swing initialisation into a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` so that it runs on the swing thread:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Password Login System");
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Password: ");
        JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
        pass.setEchoChar('*');
        pass.addActionListener(new AL());
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(pass, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.validate();
      }
    });
  }
```

See oracle docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for mode details.

Answer (score 4):

You should make your frame visible after adding contents to it:

```
  frame.add(panel);
  frame.setVisible(true); // move down here
}
```

**P.S.**  `JPanel` have default layout manager which is `FlowLayout` so all the contents would appear inline. In short, `panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST)` won't give the expected output.

Comment: While certainly a good idea, in this case, probably the preferred solution, you could also use `revalidate` and `repaint` on the frame or content pane to update the UI.  It's not a "must" do action - nit pick I know ;)