# How to show "count" MySQL query into JTextField?

Tags: java, mysql, jtextfield

Right now, I'm stuck with this problem: I want to show the total amount of songs in my database inside the GUI (through the jtextfield).

This is what I got so far:

```
txtTotalSongs = new JTextField();
txtTotalSongs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            String q = "select count (title) from songs";
            PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(q);

            ps.setInt(1, 20);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                txtTotalSongs.setText(String.valueOf("title"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
});
txtTotalSongs.setBounds(591, 458, 86, 20);
contentPane.add(txtTotalSongs);
```

Comment: what is the action you expect to be called on the JTextField, in response to which you will run actionPerformed?

Comment: well, i want the total number of rows from the database to be shown in the JTextField. does that answer your question? sorry, still a noob. @Joeblade

Comment: No the reason I asked was that you are running this code in the 'actionPerformed' part of JTextField. What action will be performed on JTextField? Ususally this is a text change or similar. on a button actionperformed would be a click. Are you sure you don't want to run this code after contentPane.add(....) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the while loop, try

```
if(rs.first())
    xtTotalSongs.setText(rs.getString("title"));
```

rs.first() returns true (and moves the pointer to the first) if there is a row in the result set. getString returns the value of the column "title" in the first row.

Since there should only be one row for "Count" (at least I guess so), this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(rs.next()){
    txtTotalSongs.setText(String.valueOf("title"));
    // This doesn't get any value from rs
    // It just get value "title".
}
```

Change your while loop as below:

```
while(rs.next())
{
    txtTotalSongs.setText(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

Comment: still didnt got what i wanted :/

Answer (score 0):

I would set this outside of the actionPerformed.

```
txtTotalSongs = new JTextField();
txtTotalSongs.setBounds(591, 458, 86, 20);
contentPane.add(txtTotalSongs);

txtTotalSongs.setText(getTotalSongs());
```

and then add a method somewhere:

```
// not ideal but trying to use most of your original code.
public int getTotalSongs() {
    try {
        String q = "select count (title) from songs";
        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(q);

        ps.setInt(1, 20);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            return rs.getInt(1);
        } else { 
            return 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return 0;
    }
}
```

if you want to regularly update the count, you can run a Timer, just be careful about [threadsafety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182316/java-swing-libraries-thread-safety) when updating.